# If $f(x)$ is continuous on $(a,b), \text{ and } x_1,x_2 \in (a,b), m_1,m_2 > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\text{If} f(x) \text{ is continuous on } (a,b), \text{ and } x_1,x_2 \in (a,b), m_1,m_2 > 0$$

$$ \text{ prove }\exists c \in (a,b) \text{ s.t. } f(c) = \frac{m_1f(x_1)+m_2f(x_2)}{m_1 + m_2}$$

I need a hint on how to prove this

Comment: Seems like a job for the mean value theorem. It might help to rewrite it with $\lambda = m_1/(m_1+m_2)$ and $1-\lambda = m_2/(m_1+m_2)$, with $\lambda \in (0,1)$ to simplify things a bit.

Comment: still can't figure it out, since $c$ is not in $[x_1,x_2]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is continuous at $[x_1,x_2]$ and

$$f([x_1,x_2])=[m,M]$$ with

$$m\le f(x_1)\le M$$
$$m\le f(x_2)\le M$$

$$m_1m\le m_1f(x_1)\le m_1M$$
$$m_2m\le m_2f(x_2)\le m_2M$$

$$m(m_1+m_2)\le m_f(x_1)+m_2f(x_2)\le M(m_1+m_2)$$

$$m\le \frac{m_1f(x_1)+m_2f(x_2)}{m_1+m_2}\le M$$

thus there exists $c\in [x_1,x_2] :$

$$\frac{m_1f(x_1)+m_2f(x_2)}{m_1+m_2}=f(c)$$

Comment: the last part is using intermediate value theorem right?

Comment: @HengWei Yes, the image if an intervall by a continuous function is an intervall.